# Trying to Stream Raspberry Pi Camera with VLC. Cannot Get VLC on Windows To Play Stream

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have tried numerous examples supposed to stream the RPi camera by VLC using RTSP and then to play the stream on a windows computer using VLC with no success.

For example on my RPi 3 with updated Jessie (on about 20170820) 
I enter in a terminal window: `raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1920 -h 1080  -fps 30 -b 1000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264`

Which I got off of a fourm ( https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=97676)
and about which was written:

```
Hi, with VLC I just need to open the network stream with this string: "rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554". I also tried with port 554 and managed to add a path (I tried with path /live.sdp), but while the stream opens with no problems in VLC, i have no luck with SS. Obviously when I changed config I changed both cvlc parameters on the Pi and vlc connection string on my pc
Yeah, I'm using Generic RTSP (I have SS 5.0.1, can't find SS Pro)

I didn't check if it was using UDP or TCP, i leaved them to default values. If I'd know what codec to use I could specify it in cvlc, but since I wasn't able to find what is supported by SS and what is not, I tried default with h264.
```

When I try to play with VLC I get the VLC error dialog with message:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554'. Check the log for details.
```

I made a wire shark caputre of the log in attempt:

```
  No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     32 2017-08-30 16:42:42.889437000 192.168.1.29          192.168.1.58          RTSP     172    OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554 RTSP/1.0

Frame 32: 172 bytes on wire (1376 bits), 172 bytes captured (1376 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: GoodWayI_11:6d:ac (00:50:b6:11:6d:ac), Dst: Raspberr_f5:b7:3e (b8:27:eb:f5:b7:3e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29), Dst: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    Version: 4
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    Total Length: 158
    Identification: 0x1fac (8108)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x5706 [validation disabled]
    Source: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    Destination: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 65024 (65024), Dst Port: 8554 (8554), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 118
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554 RTSP/1.0\r\n
    CSeq: 2\r\n
    User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.6 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)\r\n
    \r\n

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     34 2017-08-30 16:42:42.912266000 192.168.1.58          192.168.1.29          RTSP     178    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Frame 34: 178 bytes on wire (1424 bits), 178 bytes captured (1424 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Raspberr_f5:b7:3e (b8:27:eb:f5:b7:3e), Dst: GoodWayI_11:6d:ac (00:50:b6:11:6d:ac)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58), Dst: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    Version: 4
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    Total Length: 164
    Identification: 0xa134 (41268)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x1578 [validation disabled]
    Source: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    Destination: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8554 (8554), Dst Port: 65024 (65024), Seq: 1, Ack: 119, Len: 124
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Response: RTSP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
    Server: VLC/2.2.6\r\n
    Content-length: 0
    Cseq: 2\r\n
    Public: DESCRIBE,SETUP,TEARDOWN,PLAY,PAUSE,GET_PARAMETER\r\n
    \r\n

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     35 2017-08-30 16:42:42.912534000 192.168.1.29          192.168.1.58          RTSP     198    DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554 RTSP/1.0

Frame 35: 198 bytes on wire (1584 bits), 198 bytes captured (1584 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: GoodWayI_11:6d:ac (00:50:b6:11:6d:ac), Dst: Raspberr_f5:b7:3e (b8:27:eb:f5:b7:3e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29), Dst: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    Version: 4
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    Total Length: 184
    Identification: 0x1fad (8109)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x56eb [validation disabled]
    Source: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    Destination: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 65024 (65024), Dst Port: 8554 (8554), Seq: 119, Ack: 125, Len: 144
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Request: DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554 RTSP/1.0\r\n
    CSeq: 3\r\n
    User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.6 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2016.02.22)\r\n
    Accept: application/sdp\r\n
    \r\n

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     38 2017-08-30 16:42:42.998577000 192.168.1.58          192.168.1.29          RTSP/XML 371    Reply: RTSP/1.0 404 Client error

Frame 38: 371 bytes on wire (2968 bits), 371 bytes captured (2968 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Raspberr_f5:b7:3e (b8:27:eb:f5:b7:3e), Dst: GoodWayI_11:6d:ac (00:50:b6:11:6d:ac)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58), Dst: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    Version: 4
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    Total Length: 357
    Identification: 0xa136 (41270)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x14b5 [validation disabled]
    Source: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    Destination: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8554 (8554), Dst Port: 65024 (65024), Seq: 200, Ack: 263, Len: 317
[2 Reassembled TCP Segments (392 bytes): #36(75), #38(317)]
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Response: RTSP/1.0 404 Client error\r\n
    Content-length: 317
    Content-type: text/html
    \r\n
    eXtensible Markup Language

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     47 2017-08-30 16:42:43.004164000 192.168.1.29          192.168.1.58          RTSP     389    OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554 RTSP/1.0

Frame 47: 389 bytes on wire (3112 bits), 389 bytes captured (3112 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: GoodWayI_11:6d:ac (00:50:b6:11:6d:ac), Dst: Raspberr_f5:b7:3e (b8:27:eb:f5:b7:3e)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29), Dst: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    Version: 4
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    Total Length: 375
    Identification: 0x1fb4 (8116)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x5625 [validation disabled]
    Source: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    Destination: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 65028 (65028), Dst Port: 8554 (8554), Seq: 44, Ack: 1, Len: 335
[2 Reassembled TCP Segments (378 bytes): #45(43), #47(335)]
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.58:8554 RTSP/1.0\r\n
    CSeq: 1\r\n
    User-Agent: RealMedia Player Version 6.0.9.1235 (linux-2.0-libc6-i386-gcc2.95)\r\n
    ClientChallenge: 9e26d33f2984236010ef6253fb1887f7\r\n
    PlayerStarttime: [28/03/2003:22:50:23 00:00]\r\n
    CompanyID: KnKV4M4I/B2FjJ1TToLycw==\r\n
    GUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\r\n
    RegionData: 0\r\n
    ClientID: Linux_2.4_6.0.9.1235_play32_RN01_EN_586\r\n
    \r\n

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     57 2017-08-30 16:42:43.027340000 192.168.1.58          192.168.1.29          RTSP     178    Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK

Frame 57: 178 bytes on wire (1424 bits), 178 bytes captured (1424 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Raspberr_f5:b7:3e (b8:27:eb:f5:b7:3e), Dst: GoodWayI_11:6d:ac (00:50:b6:11:6d:ac)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58), Dst: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    Version: 4
    Header Length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
    Total Length: 164
    Identification: 0x7282 (29314)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x442a [validation disabled]
    Source: 192.168.1.58 (192.168.1.58)
    Destination: 192.168.1.29 (192.168.1.29)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8554 (8554), Dst Port: 65028 (65028), Seq: 1, Ack: 379, Len: 124
Real Time Streaming Protocol
    Response: RTSP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
    Server: VLC/2.2.6\r\n
    Content-length: 0
    Cseq: 1\r\n
    Public: DESCRIBE,SETUP,TEARDOWN,PLAY,PAUSE,GET_PARAMETER\r\n
    \r\n
```

Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer to my question at this forum:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132116
[Solution here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132116)

The answer was to add a file name to the rtsp stream.

From:

> raspivid -o - -e -t 0 -p 0,0,640,480 -w 680 -h 480  -fps 30  -g 30 -ih
>   -pf baseline -md 4 -k -b 1000000 | cvlc -A-vvv  alsa,none -v stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264

To:

> raspivid -o - -e -t 0 -p 0,0,640,480 -w 680 -h 480  -fps 30  -g 30 -ih
>   -pf baseline -md 4 -k -b 1000000 | cvlc -A-vvv  alsa,none -v stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/x}' :demux=h264

Here I will try to bold it.
raspivid -o - -e -t 0 -p 0,0,640,480 -w 680 -h 480  -fps 30  -g 30 -ih -pf baseline -md 4 -k -b 1000000 | cvlc -A-vvv  alsa,none -v stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554**/x**}' :demux=h264